# Logical question with a balance and flour

Tags: logic

**The problem is:** I have a balance of $9$ kgs of flour and two weights; $250$g and $50$g. In the matter of $3$ steps I have to divide them into $2$ bags of $7$ and $2$ kg, respectively. I know that after I have measured a bag with $250$g I can combine it with the $250$ weight, so $500$g in total for example. Using the balance counts as a step! So you can use the balance only 3 times.
I hope you understand my English :]

Comment: For reference: what counts as a step? Just using the balance, or would combining multiple bags (see my answer) count as a step? Also, can we use as many bags as we want?

Comment: @DylanSp I assume only a weighing counts as a step. If so, under a reasonable interpretation of "weighing", it can be done in three steps. If combining two bags is a step, we would need more information; for example, is combining three bags one step or two?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is really to measure out $2$ kg of flour in one bag.
The second bag simply receives all the remaining flour.

If you are allowed to put two bags on the scale and then transfer flour
between them until the scale balances, you can use the scale to
divide a bag of flour in half in one step.
Put the bag to be divided on one side of the scale,
put an empty bag on the other side, 
and transfer flour between the bags until they balance.

Assuming you can divide a bag as described above,
here is a hint about how to measure $2$ kg 
from the original $9$ kg in three steps:
$$ 9 = 2.25 \times 4. $$

Answer (score 0):

I can see how to do it in five steps; maybe someone else can suggest how to condense it further.

1. Start with all the flour in bag $A$. Put the $250$ g weight on one side of the scale. Pour flour from $A$ into bag $B$ on the other side of the scale until it balances the weight. $B$ now contains $250$ g of flour.
2. Put $B$ and the $250$ g weight on one side of the scale. Pour flour from $A$ into bag $C$ on the other side of the scale until it balances. $B$ has $250$ g, $C$ has $500$ g.
3. Put $B$, $C$, and the $250$ g weight on one side of the scale. Pour flour from $A$ into bag $D$ on the other side until it balances. $B$ has $250$ g, $C$ has $500$ g, $D$ has $1000$ g.
4. Repeat step 1 with a new bag $E$ in place of $B$. $B$ has $250$ g, $C$ has $500$ g, $D$ has $1000$ g, $E$ has $250$ g.
5. Combine bags $B, C, D, E$ into one bag, which will have $250 + 500 + 1000 + 250 = 2000$ g. $A$ started with $9000$ g; with $2000$ g removed, it's left with $7000$ g, and we're done.

(We can also get $1000$ g in $E$ in step 4 by weighing it against $D$, then condense $D$ and $E$ into our $2$ kg bag, and recombine $A, B, C$ for $7$ kg. This doesn't save any steps, though.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I am allowed to answer on my question but I solve it.
First I combine the 250 and 50g weight and I got a bag of 300g.
Then I combine the bag of 300g and the weights of 250g and 50g - I get a bag of 600g. Then lastly I combine the 600g and 300g bag the 250 weight and put the 50g weight on the other side of the balance. I got a bag with 1100g. 
1100g + 600g + 300g = 2000g = 2kg.